# Hibernate: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.(Z)V

Tags: hibernate, struts2

When i access to my app login page, the page is loaded. But i a enter a login and password to access to another page i have an exception:

```
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:   
org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.(Z)V
File:   net/sf/cglib/core/DebuggingClassWriter.java
Line number:    47
Stacktraces
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)


java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.(Z)V

    net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
    net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
    net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
    net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:69)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:111)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:269)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:425)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
    org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1218)
    fr.si2m.occ.dao.sessions.HibernateFactory.(HibernateFactory.java:56)
    fr.si2m.occ.dao.interfaces.AbstractDAO.(AbstractDAO.java:26)
    fr.si2m.occ.dao.impl.MessageDAOImpl.(MessageDAOImpl.java:19)
    fr.si2m.occ.utils.MessageUtils.listMessages(MessageUtils.java:22)
    fr.si2m.occ.web.actions.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:128)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I think i have a conflict but i don't know which one. Here is my pom file :

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sas</groupId>
        <artifactId>sas.core</artifactId>
        <version>902000</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
      <version>2.1_3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.ga</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.ga</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.21</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sas</groupId>
      <artifactId>sas.core</artifactId>
      <version>902300</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sas</groupId>
      <artifactId>sas.svc.connection</artifactId>
      <version>902300</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.4.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.4.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
      <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
          <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
      <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
      <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.4.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
          <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0-v_771</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-jasperreports-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.19</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
      <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
      <version>R8pre2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mentaframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>mentawai</artifactId>
      <version>1.13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xalan</groupId>
      <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
          <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Could you give me some help please ?

Comment: You can take the asm dependency out of your pom. Hibernate will pull it into your project transitively.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your response. It works

Comment: Great. I've made it an answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: it's done Alex. One more time thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the asm dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

from your pom.

Hibernate will pull it into your project transitively (at the correct version) so there is no need to include it in your pom. Adding un-necessary dependencies will often lead to incorrect versions of required jars being included.